# Coloured shadowbox around equations?

Tags: equations, boxes, shadows

I currently put some boxes around equations using:

```
\newcommand*\eqbox[1]{
\definecolor{shadowcolor}{RGB}{0, 0, 102}\setlength\shadowsize{2pt}\shadowbox*{#1}
}
\eqbox{$1+1=2$}
```

How to have the same visual result but with equations between `\begin{equation}\end{equation}` ?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}

\newcommand*\eqbox[1]{\definecolor{shadowcolor}{RGB}{0, 0, 102}\setlength\shadowsize{2pt}\shadowbox*{#1}}
\begin{document}
\eqbox{$1+1 = 2$} % OK
\eqbox{\begin{equation}1+1 = 2\end{equation}} % NOT OK
\begin{equation}\eqbox{1+1 = 2}\end{equation} %OK
\begin{equation}\eqbox{r_{s} = \frac{2GM}{c^{2}}}\end{equation} % NOT OK
\end{document}
```

Note: I do not want the equation number to be in the box...

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry for that : MWE added

Comment: Perhaps you should consider `tcolorbox`es instead?

Comment: Or maybe the hf-tikz package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `empheq` does this quite easily:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fancybox,xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}

\definecolor{shadowcolor}{RGB}{0, 0, 102}
\newcommand*\eqbox[1]{%
  \setlength\shadowsize{2pt}%
  \shadowbox*{#1}%
}


\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{empheq}[box=\eqbox]{equation}
1+1 = 2
\end{empheq}
Some text
\begin{empheq}[box=\eqbox]{align}
r_{s} &= \dfrac{2GM}{c^{2}} \\
v &= ab+cd
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this something I like? No.

Answer (score 2):

`equation` needs somme space for the reference, then one has to use a `minipage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}

\newcommand*\eqbox[1]{\definecolor{shadowcolor}{RGB}{0, 0, 102}\setlength\shadowsize{2pt}\shadowbox*{#1}}

\newcommand{\EqBox}[2][.8]{%
    \definecolor{shadowcolor}{RGB}{0, 0, 102}
    \setlength\shadowsize{2pt}
    \begin{equation}
        \shadowbox*{%
        \begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}
        \[#2\]
        \end{minipage}      
        }
    \end{equation}
    }

\begin{document}
\eqbox{$1+1 = 2$} % OK
\begin{equation}\eqbox{1+1 = 2}\end{equation} %OK


\EqBox[.27]{r_{s} = \dfrac{2GM}{c^{2}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes... except that I do not want the number to be in the box...

Comment: Not so piece of cake... (it works for 1+1=2 but not for things with math symbols -> see the edited MWE)

Comment: Let's try again ;-)